# Allow the user to search a specific staff in system

Tags: c

```
void searchStaff() {

int id, found;
struct staff sta;
FILE*fp2, *temp;

printf("Enter the ID number you want to search:\n ");
scanf("%d", &id);

fp2 = fopen("Staff", "rb");
temp = fopen("temp", "wb");
printf("Staff Details\n");
printf("ID NUMBERS\t NAME\n");
printf("=========================");
while (fread(&sta, sizeof(sta), 1, fp2) 
{
    if (id == sta.id) {
        printf("%d\t\t %s\n", sta.id, sta.name);
        found = 1;

    }
    else {
        fp2 = (NULL);
        printf("No such record!!");
        fwrite(&sta, sizeof(sta), 1, temp);
        found = 0;

    }
}
fclose(fp2);
fclose(temp);
if (found == 1) {
    system("Staff");
}
}
```

It will trigger the break point during the while line...but it won't display the results.  How do i fix it? It is supposed to read the ID in and display the results.

Comment: 1 - what type is sta.id and 2 - when the **first** record read isn't the one you look for, you `fp2 = (NULL);` ... You should review that logic

Comment: What is the `staff` file? How is it created? You are reading from this file with `fread` expecting it contain some data, and then you execute the `staff` file with `system(staff")`. What is `system(staff")` supposed to do? What _exact_  error message is displayed when you run your program?

Comment: typedef struct staff {
 
 int id,salary;
 char name[30], position[30];

}staff;

Comment: no error massage display....it just trigger break point during    while (fread(&sta, sizeof(sta), 1, fp2)!=0)

Comment: @Hshdhx please answer the questions in my last comment. And please make clear what your program is _actually_ supposed to do. Read this: [ask] and this: [tour].

Comment: system("Staff"); is i excepting return the the data and store it. the whole program is allow user the search the staff record and display the staff record, if the record exist, display it and if didn't exist, display no such record and back to main.

Comment: How is the `staff` file created? Does it _actually_ exist? You don't check if `fopen` fails. If `fopen` returns `NULL`, the file could not be opened (most likely because it does not exist) and reading from a `NULL` file pointer is "undefined hevaviour" (google that term).

Comment: Sorry I meant "undefined behaviour (google that term)".

Comment: f = fopen("staff", "rw");
if (f == NULL) {
    perror("Failed: ");
    return 1;
}    i add this code and now it wont trigger the break point it show Failed:no such file or directory